# Bayesian posterior from pairwise comparison of observations

Tags: bayesian, nonparametric

Say I have $n$ observations of group $A$ and $m$ observations of group $B$ and a function $f: A\times B \rightarrow C$ mapping a pair of observations to one of $k$ categories.

I am interested in the posterior distributions of the probabilities $P(f(a, b) = c_i)$, and I intend to use a uniform Dirichlet prior, so that the posterior is also Dirichlet distributed. If I have understood correctly, the parameters should then be $\alpha_i = 1 + d\cdot P(f(a, b) = c_i)$ for some number $d$ that says how many observations of the application of $f$ have.

However, I am very unsure what value $d$ should have. My intuition says that $d$is sort of like degrees of freedom, and should be something like $m + n$, the number of actual observations I have, but I haven't been able to find anything to support this. So I have two questions:

- If possible, what should $d$ be here to get a correct posterior distribution
- Is there any literature I can refer to for this problem